# Google Spreadsheets: Use row of nth occurrence of value for other calculations?

Tags: google-sheets

I am using a combination of Google Forms and Google Spreadsheets for data entry and interpretation for scouting in a robotics competition (FRC). The user fills out a form for each match with the data from 6 different teams. That data is put into a spreadsheet by the form, and the sheet of data is used by other sheets for interpretation, and it outputs different stats.

One of the sheets is designed to show the progression of the team's stats over the course of their 9-10 matches. I want it to show the values for a certain stat in the same order as the matches that they played (Match 1: 10 points; Match 2: 15 points; etc.). The problem is that there are upwards of 40 teams, so teams don't play back-to-back. I am trying to create a function that searches for the nth occurrence, by row, in the 6 columns that contain team numbers. That function would then use that row to return a value for a stat by that team from that match.

My spreadsheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvPTkrt7f7AYdDlWS2FXNFN3ekVZTGtkU0VNZlRiUlE&usp=sharing). The sheet of raw data is called "Games", and the sheet containing the progression data is called "Over Time". Within the "Games" sheet, each line is a match, and there is data for each of the 6 teams in each line. Each team gets a line on the "Over Time" sheet, and each stat would take up about 10 columns.

The function would search for the nth time (as specified by the number in row 2) that the team number (as specified in column A) occurs. It would then search that row number for the team number and return the value in the column specified by the function (eg. If the team number occurs in column C, return the value in column E of the same row.). In the sheet "Averages", I used mainly SUMIF and COUNTIF functions to return averages for each stat, but I can't figure out how to use the array functions that would be necessary for the first step of this function. I would prefer to avoid using hidden columns and rows, as that just gets messy, so it would be great if the entire function is in one cell. I would also prefer it to be a function, as opposed to a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses one function per row (not one function for the entire table). In 'Over Time'!B3:

`=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT('Games'!E$2:BW&CHAR(9);('Games'!C$2:BU=A3)*(MOD(COLUMN('Games'!C$2:BU$2);14)=3)));CHAR(9)))`

which can be filled down to B8.

If it is absolutely necessary to have one formula for the entire table, then I'm sure it could  be done, but it will be horribly complex. Further, as it is, these "concatenate then split" type formulae (which you need to resort to when the data isn't nicely vertical) are quite inefficient, depending on how big your source data gets. That may not be an issue in your case, but for big source data sets, I would prefer a custom function for performanc ein this case.

Comment: I'm sorry; let me clarify. I meant that the formula for each cell should be contained within that cell, as opposed to having multiple steps for each statistic. There would be one formula for each cell that has a statistic.

Comment: OK so can i confirm there are two issues here: 1. You need to populate the 'Over Time' sheet (does the formula I posted work for this?) and 2. You want to simplify the formulae you have already used in the` 'Averages' sheet?

Comment: The formula does exactly what it was designed to do, but how would I modify it to work for more statistics? As far as the latter problem, those formulas were made while in a hurry before last year's competition. For now, they work, and that is my goal for now. Eventually, I will make it so that we don't need to edit it every year, but that is for when I actually have the time to do so.

Comment: Never mind, I figured out how to edit. Thank you so much! Just as a point of curiosity, is it possible to simplify equations like those used in "Averages"? Also, the equations in "Most Recent" are obscenely long, and I know it is possible to simplify them, but could I use arrays to just return the entire, most recent data set for each team with one equation?